# (Apache) Regex to match a specific cookie name+value (to strip/remove it)?

Tags: regex, apache, cookies, request-headers, mod-headers

I am trying to use a "RequestHeader edit" directive to take the "Cookie" header, and remove a specific cookie from that header.

In other words, suppose the incoming "Cookie" header was:

```
Cookie: header1=123; myheader=abc; header2=789
```

I want to use "RequestHeader edit" to modify that "Cookie" header to:

```
Cookie: header1=123; header2=789
```

Or, as another example, if the incoming "Cookie" header was:

```
Cookie: header1=123; header2=789; myheader=abc
```

change that to:

```
Cookie: header1=123; header2=789
```

I'm horrible with regexes, but the closest I have been able to get to is this:

RequestHeader edit `Cookie "myheader=.*(;)|myheader=.*($)" ""`

But, even that has a problem, that if the "myheader" cookie is the last one in the "Cookie" string/value, I'm ending up with a semi-colon (";") at the end.

Can anyone provide a regex that would do this completely correctly?

Thanks,
Jim

P.S.  I'm also wondering:  Is the Cookie with the trailing semi-colon valid?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
RequestHeader edit Cookie "(^myheader=[^;]*; |; myheader=[^;]*)" ""
```

Comment: Salman,  Thanks.  I just tried what you suggested, and it gives the same ("almost" correct) result, i.e., if the "myheader" cookie name/value pair is the very last cookie, at the end of the "Cookie" value/string, the regex you suggested leaves a trailing semicolon (";").

Comment: Salman - I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "check the edit"?

Comment: I have edited my answer. It should work in four cases (`myheader` is in the beginning, middle, end or not present at all).

Comment: salman - PERFECT!!!  Just one additional question if I might, about the edited regex...  are the outermost parenthenses necessary, and if so, why?  Thanks, Jim

Comment: I guess that was actually TWO questions :)...  Jim

Comment: The outer parenthesis are _not_ required. They create a back reference , which are useful, but not required in your case.